# Ссылка на картинку с капчей вк. Отправка на antigate

Tags: java, html, вконтакте

Нужно отправлять на сервер антигейт картинку для розгадки с капчей
Получаю капчу типа `https://api.vk.com/captcha.php?sid=579356847070&s=1`
получается это ссылка не на фото а на html страницу где есть капча
Пробовал розпарсить html чтобы получить ссылку вида [http://ссылка.jpj](http://%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0.jpj), но ссылка совпадает с адресом на html-страницу и когда я передаю эту ссылку на сервер antigate, то получаю `ERROR_ZERO_CAPTCHA_FILESIZE`
Вопрос. Как получить из ссылки вида `https://api.vk.com/captcha.php?sid=579356847070&s=1, чисто ссылку на картинку. Спасибо

Comment: Вообще-то вы и так получаете картинку. Не могу точно сказать в чём проблема вашего антигейта. Вероятно, он не умеет определять mime-type. Уточните, пожалуйста, есть там документация какая-то? Вероятно, они говорят, в каком случае выбрасывается такое исключение.

Comment: @ higimo ERROR_ZERO_CAPTCHA_FILESIZE 0 Размер капчи, которую вы прислали, равен 0 байтам. Обратитесь к разработчику вашего софта за разъяснениями.

Comment: Попробуйте загрузить файл программой (не могу подсказать решения на java) и проверить размер файла прямо в коде и его mime-type.

Comment: @ higimo, пробовал, размер возле 2200 байт

Comment: Пожалуйста, попробуйте http://api.vk.com/captcha.php?sid=579356847070&s=1 (не https, а htttp) такой адрес скормить антигейту. Если не получится, то лично у меня больше нет идей.

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопрос следует адресовать в соответствующую техподдержку.